# Effects of a Magento core modification that disables cart input filtering?

Tags: php, mysql, security, magento, sql-injection

I'm currently working on an already modified version of magento (v 1.6.1).
The previous developers have modified the app/core itself, what if I upgrade to the 1.7?
It would restore original app/core, am I right? (because I know every mod should be placed under app/local)

Then I noticed, by running diff on the ecommerce and a clean 1.6.1 installation that the developers have applied this modification (lines marked with "<" was the original content and ">" the edited one)

```
diff app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
169c169,170
<                 $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
---
>                 #$params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
>                 $params['qty'] = $params['qty'];
311c312,313
<                 $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
---
>                 #$params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
>                 $params['qty'] = $params['qty'];
383c385,386
<                         $cartData[$index]['qty'] = $filter->filter(trim($data['qty']));
---
>                         //$cartData[$index]['qty'] = $filter->filter(trim($data['qty']));
>                         $cartData[$index]['qty'] = $data['qty'];
```

As you may notice they disabled $filter->filter and trim.

**Doesn't this expose the e-store to SQLInjections or similiar arbitrary code execution?**
Is there another check that magento performs before to store this data inside the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter functions that the previous developers removed are not used to filter input for SQL injection or other security risks. They are used for converting localized input to a standard form that can be processed regardless of locale. Here's the expanded context for the first diff:

```
$filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
    array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
);
$params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
```

See the Zend documentation for [details on what LocalizedToNormal](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.set.html) does.

Magento has built-in safeguards to prevent SQL injection by using standard database classes that filter all data before constructing a query. That logic is located in the Mage_Core_Model_Resource_* classes as well as the Zend libraries stored in /lib/Zend. As long as the previous developers didn't modify those classes, there shouldn't be additional SQL risk.

Cross-site scripting is always a potential issue, of course, but the risk there typically lies more at the View layer (PHTML & Block classes) than at the Controller or Model layers.